# Send -MailMessage -Attachments will not accept null for any variables

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm using the Send-MailMessage function in Powershell v2.0 I'm using variables for the attachments as there will not always be attachments being sent. If there are no attachments (file locations) in the variables, I get an error otherwise it works. How I can I setup the Send-MailMessage function to output attachments and at other times not without it failing.

```
Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml –From Monitoring@CorporateActions -Priority $Priority –To "steven.meadows@dionglobal.eu" -Attachments $IDCSwiftLogFileAttachment,$SecurityLogFileAttachment, $ClientTypeLogFileAttachment –Subject “Corporate Actions Overnight Processing” –Body "<b><u> Download Status: </u></b> <br><br> $SWIFTDownloadErrorMessage $SecurityDownloadErrorMessage $ClientDownloadErrorMessage $HoldingDownloadErrorMessage $CLISLOOKDownloadErrorMessage $SWIFTDownloadSuccessMessage $SecurityDownloadSuccessMessage $ClientDownloadSuccessMessage $HoldingDownloadSuccessMessage $CLISLOOKDownloadSuccessMessage <b><u> X-Gen Processing Status: </u></b> <br><br> $SWIFTXGenNoInputMessage $SecurityXGenNoInputMessage $ClientXGenNoInputMessage $HoldingXGenNoInputMessage $CLISLOOKXGenNoInputMessage $IDCSwiftXGenSuccessMessage $SecurityXGenSuccessMessage $ClientXgenSuccessMessage $HoldingXgenSuccessMessage $ClientTypeXGenSuccessMessage $IDCSwiftXgenErrorMessage $SecurityXgenErrorMessage $ClientXgenErrorMessage $HoldingXgenErrorMessage $ClientTypeXGenErrorMessage”  –SmtpServer smtp.investmaster.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a "splat" parameter: a hash of {parameter name, parameter value} to avoid passing the `Attachments` parameter when not needed:

```
$attachments = @()
if ($IDCSwiftLogFileAttachment) {
  $attachments += $IDCSwiftLogFileAttachment
}
# Repeat for each potential parameter

$params = @{}
if ($attachments.Length -gt 0) {
  $params['Attachments'] = $attachments
}

Send-MailMessage @params -BodyAsHtml –From Monitoring@CorporateActions -Priority $Priority # Other parameters
```

(This ability to use a hash table to pass parameters was added in PowerShell V2.)

Comment: Excellent answer Richard. I see what you're doing there.. I'm getting the error 'Missing or invalid array index expression' though when I run the script...

Comment: @steven Would need to see on what line the error was happening to be able to help.

Comment: The line is>>>> $params[String]['-Attachments '] = $attachments()

Comment: @steven Take another look at the script in my answer: 1. no "-" on the argument name in the hash, 2. no cast (`[string]`), 3. `$attachments` is not a function so drop the `()`.

Comment: I went back to you original script and have the error: Array assignment to [Attachments] failed: Cannot convert value "Attachments" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

This is for the line: $params['Attachments'] = $attachments

Comment: Do I not need to cast String then or something else?

Comment: @steven: There was also a typo in the A, `@()` creates an empty array, it should have been `@{}` to create an empty hash. Now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you wrote the function the easiest way is to put the variable for the attachmate last
posh will accept leaving off if its the last one in the function call

it may not be fancy or correct but i have been using that method with an email function i wrote for a couple years now with no problem