# How to make attachment in Send-MailMessage optional?

Tags: powershell

I amd using Send-MailMessage in my script

```
Send-MailMessage -From 'User01 <user01@fabrikam.com>' -To 'User02 <user02@fabrikam.com>', 'User03 <user03@fabrikam.com>' -Subject 'Sending the Attachment' -Body 'Forgot to send the attachment. Sending now.' -Attachments .\data.csv -Priority High -DeliveryNotificationOption OnSuccess, OnFailure -SmtpServer 'smtp.fabrikam.com'
```

it works great, except sometimes when a log file fails to get created, thus no attachment, Send-MailMessage fails to send an email because attachment is not there. 
how can i keep the `-attachment` switch as part of `Send-MailMessage` and still send email even if somehow the attachment fails?

something like this: `-Attachments (mandatory=$false)$attachment`

Comment: [There is a great answer to your question right here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560270/send-mailmessage-attachments-will-not-accept-null-for-any-variables)

Comment: [There is a great answer to your question right here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560270/send-mailmessage-attachments-will-not-accept-null-for-any-variables)

Comment: @avic Interesting,  splatting huh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I agree with [avic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9960311/avic) that using splatting is the way to go with cmdlets like `Send-MailMessage` that use a lot of parameters, there may also be another way, keeping your format sort-of intact.

The `-Attachments` parameter is of type string[] (an array of file names) and what's more, it can be piped to the Send-MailMessage cmdlet. As long as it is an array, the cmdlet seems fine with it, even if the array is empty.
You could use that to change the command you have to this:

```
# see if the file to attach is there and if not make $attachments an empty array
if (Test-Path -Path '.\data.csv' -PathType Leaf) { $attachments = @('.\data.csv') } else { $attachments = @() }

# pipe the attachments array to the cmdlet
$attachments | Send-MailMessage -From 'User01 <user01@fabrikam.com>' -To 'User02 <user02@fabrikam.com>', 'User03 <user03@fabrikam.com>' -Subject 'Sending the Attachment' -Body 'Forgot to send the attachment. Sending now.' -Priority High -DeliveryNotificationOption OnSuccess, OnFailure -SmtpServer 'smtp.fabrikam.com'
```

As said, personally I would prefer using [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) for this..

Comment: Are priority and delivery notifications required?

Comment: @Cataster no, it is up to you if you want to use them. See [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6#parameters) parameters

Comment: Btw, currently, I am using an attachments variable (array) that carries multiple attachments. So I guess this will be as easy as just piping it to the beginning,  but I am surprised, I dont see -attachments switch in the cmdlet in your answer. How does send mail know what the variable piped is supposed to be?

Comment: I guess one of the reasons I am hesitant to change my mail sending to splatting is because I have so many send mail throughout my script its gonna be tedious to change. Also, I would have to specify the $params variable after my current sendmail message variables (such as $attachments, $subject, etc...) which is gonna be a pain because I have them defined throughout my script in different places. Powershell is sequential execution,  so it's not gonna recognize the variables if I define splatting before them

Comment: @Cataster If you look at the description of the parameters in the link I commented, you can see the `Attachments` parameter is the only parameter that accepts pipeline input. `True (ByValue)`, so that is why the cmdlet knows what that variable is supposed to be. If your script has many of these commands, then why not create your own function to accept the same arguments as the Send-MailMessage cmdlet, do parameter checking etc. in there and create a splat hashtable to work with. Then all you have to do is change the calls to Send-MailMessage into the name of your own function.